# how to take different counts from single table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named - `studentId_t`
which is having fields:

- SrNo.
- classId
- StudentId
- StudentName
- Status
- Creation Date
- Modified Date

and another table named `studentE`
which is having fields

- SrNo.
- classId
- studentId
- studentAdd
- EId

-- 
I want to check status of student and I am having only E_id

I was trying query like ..

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS ST FROM `StuInfo`.`studentId_t` S, `StuInfo`.`studentE` SE
    WHERE S.`status` = 'ST'
    AND SE.`studentId` = S.`studentId`
    AND SE.`EId` = 1
```

but here, I want to calculate status in (ST, BS, BH, GN), So how can i calculate it in single query from above query I am able to calculate single status, I want multiple status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE `SUM()` with `if,else` conditions oriented to all status.

Try like below:

```
SELECT SUM(if(status='ST',1,0))  AS ST , SUM(if(status='BS',1,0))  AS   BS,
SUM(if(status='BH',1,0))  AS BH,SUM(if(status='GN',1,0))  AS GN
FROM StuInfo.studentId_t S, StuInfo.studentE SE
WHERE S.status IN ('ST', 'BH','BS','GN') AND SE.studentId = S.studentId AND SE.EId = 1
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(if(status='ST',1,0))  AS ST , SUM(if(status='BS',1,0))  AS   BS,
SUM(if(status='BH',1,0))  AS BH,SUM(if(status='GN',1,0))  AS GN
FROM StuInfo.studentId_t S, StuInfo.studentE SE
WHERE S.status IN ('ST', 'BH','BS','GN') AND SE.studentId = S.studentId AND SE.EId = 1

Comment: just a little change, need to use 'IN' in where clause